# How to compare message.author on guild, and user on reaction

Tags: discord.py

I want to compare :

1. `user` from `on_reaction_add(reaction, user)` on DM channel
2. `member` (which is saved by `on_message` on some guild before, `member = message.author`. )

but `message.author` seems it does not hold the ID of the DM channel. Then how do I compare `member` and `user`?

Comment: Simply do `member == user` and it'll work, internally it checks for the IDs

Comment: Hmm, it keeps ignoring my reactions on new messages too. How do I make the same thing with `on_raw_reaction_add`? Can I do `client.get_user(payload.user_id)`?